# Issues after installing TFS 2015(Update3)

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Recently I have installed TFS 2015 in DEV environment by restoring the Databases from PROD.
After installing and configuring all the necessary steps in TFS admin console, now I am facing issues. In the TFS web,I am able to see source code but not workitems. when I click on the workitems and settings it throws me an SQL error.

I tried to installed from the scratch and reconfigured databases but I still face the same issues.

Below is the error:

TF246021: An error occurred while processing your request. Technical information (for administrator): SQL Server Error: 1224

Comment: You can try to recreate your workspace to check if it help, and check following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746267/how-to-solve-tfs-error-tf246021-and-sql-server-error-500200-while-checking-in

Comment: Below is one of the errors I am facing when I clicked on editing the build definition.     500: An invalid application lock resource was passed to xp_userlock.
 An invalid application lock resource was passed to xp_userlock.
TFS.WebApi.Exception: An invalid application lock resource was passed to xp_userlock.
An invalid application lock resource was passed to xp_userlock.

Comment: Check if this thread give any help:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3f1c36b-2762-4cc9-b94f-ee7bd9de82db/tfs-upgrade-error-an-invalid-application-lock-resource-was-passed-to-xpuserlock?forum=tfsadmin